# Getting error while running adb shell screenrecord

Tags: android, adb, screen-recording

I am getting an error while running below command for recording my phones screen.

```
adb shell screenrecord /storage/external_SD/video.mp4
```

Below is the error coming-

> WARNING: linker: libcamalgo.so has text relocations. This is wasting
>   memory and is a security risk. Please fix. open devmap failed

I am trying this on a real device that is LG G Pro Lite with Android version 4.4.2.
Dont know about this error and because of the same i am not able to record the screen.

Comment: This is a warning **not an error**, so it is **not the cause** of any difficulty you are experiencing. It's unclear that it has anything to do with that command, but unless you are doing NDK development or able to upgrade whatever component is causing it, there is nothing you can do to make it go away.  "Open devmap failed" on the other hand might be part of a problem, but is too truncated to really tell.

Comment: This is all what i get as output and also screnn recording is not started.

Comment: Check logcat.  That will not be all you get **if you use the logcat tool properly**.  To put it another way, if that were the sum total of the messages, we would need to close this a duplicate of the existing question which explains why the relocations message is irrelevant and unfixable - an outcome which would not be helpful for the apparently real problem you are  trying to solve.